# Scala Reflection: How to find vals having a specified type?

Tags: scala, reflection

I am trying to implement a deep equals comparison using reflection. 
For that I need to find lists in an object given at runtime (in the example below this object is called `Foo`).

My feeling is that the code below is going towards the right direction, however I cannot figure out what to put into the `??? what should go here ???` part such that `lists` contains Symbols pointing to `list1` and `list2` ?

If I simply put `listType` into `??? what should go here ???` then `lists` becomes empty.

(The code below is taken from an IntelliJ Scala Worksheet in which I was experimenting with possible solutions.)

```
import scala.reflect.runtime.universe._
import java.util
class Foo{
  val one=1
  val list1=new util.ArrayList[Int]
  val list2=new util.ArrayList[Int]  
}
val foo=new Foo
val m= runtimeMirror(getClass.getClassLoader)
val theType =m.reflect(foo).symbol.toType
val listType = typeOf[util.List[_]]
val lists=theType.members.filter(  _.typeSignature == ??? what should go here ??? )
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're interested in `val`s only:

```
val lists = theType.members.filter {
  m => m.isTerm && m.asTerm.isVal && m.typeSignature <:< listType
}
```

Be aware that this includes only accessible members.